# Question about weapon proficiency for Race and Class

Tags: pathfinder-1e, weapons, sorcerer

Can my Sorcerer use a rapier without the penalty of -4, when I have racial proficiency in it from being Drow?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes. The penalty is for only for non-proficiency. It doesn't matter where the proficiency comes from.

Comment: Correct; your character gains both racial and class proficiencies.